# Table/Summary of Theorems and Definitions

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, theorems, ntheorem

I was wondering if there are any packages out there that will automatically print out a table or summary of the theorems and definitions in my document. I do NOT want a list of the theorems and definitions. Thanks.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%  PACKAGES  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%  THEOREMS  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\theoremstyle{plain} % other options: definition, remark
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{definition}{Definition} % the star prevents numbering
\theoremstyle{example}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  PAGE SETUP %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Real Analysis} % Left Header
\rhead{\thepage} % Right Header
\cfoot{} % Center Foot (empty)



%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT BEGINS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\section{Lecture 1}

\begin{theorem}
This is my first theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
My first definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
This is my second theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
My second definition.
\end{definition}


\newpage

\section{Definition and Theorem Summary}
\textbf{Theorem 1.} This is my first theorem.\\
\textbf{Definition.} My first definition.\\
\textbf{Theorem 2.} This is my second theorem.\\
\textbf{Definition.} My second definition.\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What is the difference between a table or summary and a list? Please give us an MWE which shows one of your theorems and one of your definitions and show us (if needed in Word...) what you which to get from this. Thank you.

Comment: Look at the `thmtools` package

Comment: I have checked out thmtools package, but it seems to only offer a list. Just a listing of the titles of the theorem accompanied by page number. What I want is like a cheat sheet of all the definitions and theorems from the document. I hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: It's still not at all clear me what you want:) Are you asking for al the theorems/definitions to be restarted at the beginning or end of your document? It wold be easier if you added  an example of the output of what you want to your question.

Comment: it sounds like you want to "save up" the theorems, as well as set them, and then produce either a separate document containing the saved theorems, or something like an appendix at the end of your document.  is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want! An appendix at the end of document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsfonts}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[chapter]

% --------------------------------------------
% --------------------------------------------
% Select the appropriate switch depending on your operating system
\newif\ifOSisUnix
\OSisUnixtrue % Unix, Linux, Mac OS X...
% \OSisUnixfalse % Windows

% Load fancyvrb
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

% Name of the scratch file: \ScratchFile is <jobname>.tmp
\newcommand{\ScratchFile}{\jobname.tmp}

% Command \SetTempFile to set names of auxiliary files where to store code.
% \SetTempFile{foo} defines \fooTempFile as <jobname>-foo.tmp and writes in this file
% the line \let\label\@gobble (this avoids warnings about multiply defined labels).
% Any existing file \fooTempFile is overwritten.

\newwrite\outputstream
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\SetTempFile}[1]{%
   \@namedef{#1TempFile}{\jobname-#1.tmp}%
   \immediate\openout\outputstream=\@nameuse{#1TempFile}%
   \immediate\write\outputstream{\string\makeatletter}%
   \immediate\write\outputstream{\string\let\string\label\string\@gobble}%
   \immediate\write\outputstream{\string\makeatother}%
   \immediate\closeout\outputstream}
\makeatother

% Command \AppendScratchFile.
% \AppendScratchFile{foo} appends the contents of \ScratchFile to those of 
% the auxiliary file \fooTempFile
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AppendScratchFile}[1]{%
   \ifOSisUnix%
      \immediate\write18{cat \ScratchFile >> \@nameuse{#1TempFile}}%
   \else%
      \immediate\write18{type \ScratchFile >> \@nameuse{#1TempFile}}%
   \fi}
\makeatother

% Environment StoreCode. Usage:
% \begin{StoreCode}{foo}
%   code 
% \end{StoreCode}
% It typesets  all the code that lies inside and saves it to the auxiliary file \fooTempFile.
% The definition is a bit tricky. It is not done through \newenvironment

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\StoreCode}[1]%
  {\gdef\TempFileSuffix{#1}%
   \VerbatimEnvironment
   \begin{VerbatimOut}{\ScratchFile}}
\def\endStoreCode{%
   \end{VerbatimOut}
   \input{\ScratchFile}%
   \AppendScratchFile{\TempFileSuffix}}
\makeatother

% Command \StoreCounterValue.
% \StoreCounterValue{count}{foo} writes in the file \fooTempFile the line
% \setcounter{count}{counter_value}. It is useful to control numbering the second
% time the code is processed.

\newcommand{\StoreCounterValue}[2]{%
   \immediate\openout\outputstream=\ScratchFile%
   \immediate\write\outputstream{\string\setcounter{#1}{\arabic{#1}}}%
   \immediate\closeout\outputstream%
   \AppendScratchFile{#2}}

% Command \InputTempFile.
% \InputTempFile{foo} inputs the file \fooTempFile
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\InputTempFile}[1]{\input{\@nameuse{#1TempFile}}}
\makeatother

% --------------------------------------------
% --------------------------------------------

% Auxiliary macro for writing maths
\newcommand{\Rset}{\mathbb{R}}

% We set the auxiliary files for storing code: thm for theorems and def for definitions.
\SetTempFile{thm}
\SetTempFile{def}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\StoreCounterValue{chapter}{thm}
\StoreCounterValue{theorem}{thm}
\StoreCounterValue{chapter}{def}

\begin{StoreCode}{def}
\begin{definition}\label{def:1}
  A function $f:\Rset\to\Rset$ is \emph{continuous} in a point
  $x_0$ if \[\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=f(x_0).\]
\end{definition}
\end{StoreCode}

\begin{StoreCode}{def}
\begin{definition}\label{def:2}
  A funci\'on $f:\Rset\to\Rset$ is \emph{derivable} in
  a point $x_0$ if \[\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}\]
  exists and is finite.  In such a case, this limit is called the
  \emph{derivative} of $f$ in $x_0$ and is denoted by $f'(x_0)$.
\end{definition}
\end{StoreCode}

The following result states the fundamental relation existing between the notions introduced in 
Definitions \ref{def:1} and \ref{def:2}.

\begin{StoreCode}{thm}
\begin{theorem}
  If $f:\Rset\to\Rset$ is derivable in $x_0$, then $f$ is continuous in $x_0$.
\end{theorem}
\end{StoreCode}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\StoreCounterValue{chapter}{thm}
\StoreCounterValue{theorem}{thm}

\begin{StoreCode}{thm}
\begin{theorem}[Rolle's Theorem]
   Let $f:[a,b]\to\Rset$ be a function continuous on $[a,b]$, derivable on
    $(a,b)$, and such that $f(a)=f(b)$. Then, there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that
    $f'(c)=0$.
\end{theorem}
\end{StoreCode}

\begin{StoreCode}{thm}
\begin{theorem}[Mean Value Theorem]
   Let $f:[a,b]\to\Rset$ be a function continuous on $[a,b]$ and derivable on
   $(a,b)$. Then, there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)$.
\end{theorem}
\end{StoreCode}

\begin{corollary}
   Let $f:[a,b]\to\Rset$ be a function continuous on $[a,b]$ and derivable on
   $(a,b)$. If, for all $x\in(a,b)$, $f'(x)\geq0$, then $f$ is increasing in $[a,b]$. 
\end{corollary}

\StoreCounterValue{theorem}{thm}

\begin{StoreCode}{thm}
\begin{theorem}[Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem]
   Let $f, g:[a,b]\to\Rset$ be two functions continuous on $[a,b]$ and derivable on
   $(a,b)$. Then, there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $g'(b)(f(b)-f(a))=f'(c)(g(b)-g(a))$.
\end{theorem}
\end{StoreCode}

\chapter*{Main definitions}
\InputTempFile{def}

\chapter*{Main results}
\InputTempFile{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It didn't seem to work for me. I changed the OSisUnixtrue to OSisUnixfalse, but it didn't work.